# Upgrading a server that's hosting CiviCRM to get to PHP 7

Tags: drupal, php, webserver

I did the deed and upgraded from Debian 8 to 9 and from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.0. I wanted 7.1 but the host recommended I stick with the native packages since the 7.1 broke the SOAP function. I've been having all kinds of issues since the upgrade, such as users getting a DB error when trying to subscribe or use the contribution form, and numerous issues or errors in the log. Without going into that detail, I am wondering if there was any provisioning I need to do? I tested it all on a different PHP 7.1 server without issue.

- How can I check the database integrity, etc. of the CiviCRM and is there a checklist to make sure the upgrade didn't break something
- Is there a pre and post-upgrade CRM and server provisioning checklist?
- What is the recommended MySQL version?

It seems like some simple setting got overwritten somewhere on the server.

Drupal 7, CiviCRM 5.7.2

An example of the problems we've run into since upgrading the server, no settings in CiviCRM or Drupal were changed and to my knowledge, no file permissions were changed:

- Postfix status is excited
- CiviSMTP keeps sending a notification that our password and username is wrong but testing the settings in CiviCRM and CiviSMTP reports that they are correct
- The soap user also had an issue and our first mailing had a 100% failure rate. My host downgraded to PHP7.0 to stick with native Debian 9 packages. Mailings seem to work now
- CiviMail drafts take forever to save or give an error that they can't be saved because content is out of date (posted separately)
- CiviCRM sometimes runs very slowly
- Users get an unknown db_error when trying to submit a contribution form (a lot of the time but not every time, posting separately)
- Unknown DB Error for query `UPDATE  civicrm_mailing`. Error includes the full HTML of the email. (Submitting separately).
- Several/constant MySQL deadlocks
- Several in log: "We can't load the requested web page. This requires cookies to be enabled...". (Submitting separately).

I want to post in server fault also but when they see "CiviCRM" they might assume it goes here.

Comment: I've changed a few on a hosted platform and there have been no issues, just change the version and go.  Is there anything that makes you suspect the issues are to do with php rather than something else in the upgrade?

Comment: I suspect it's not PHP related. I think this is a bad post but can't figure out what I'm asking.

Comment: Ok!  Did you upgrade the server, or move to a different server?  Log entries might help us give you some suggestions

Comment: Might be worth checking your php requirements again against https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/#php  I've seen php extensions not get upgraded properly - ie were active in old php and not after upgrading

Comment: I had the server upgraded by the host but it's the same server. I'll post an example of some of the errors that are being logged though I may post them as separate questions.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a collection of issues, not just a single one, even if they all originated from the OS upgrade.

1. The CiviCRM status page (assuming it loads) does a pretty good job of checking the usual suspects. I don't think your db would be corrupted.
2. The CiviSTMP error sounds like the crypto issue. I'd guess that your mailouts are being triggered by a cron running a different php (different version, or different packages).
3. CiviMail drafts issue + civi running slowly, but only sometimes, both sound like mysql issues. My guess is that your upgrade involved some other changes in the network or mysql settings. For erratic issues, I would definitely finger your provider, not CiviCRM.
4. Unknown db error - you'll need to look at the detailed error log (sure, install my log viewer!).